# Sencha extjs 5.0.1: messagebox rtl on move it moves in the opposite direction

Tags: extjs, messagebox, right-to-left, extjs5

I upgraded from Extjs 5.0 to 5.0.1, Then I noticed that the message box moves to the wrong direction (away from the mouse) if the viewport rtl is set to true.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salam Alikum from Israel.

Messagebox is a painful subject in Extjs5. Msgbox.confirm doesn't auto-fit itself to text, rtl support is poor and the scrollbars are a mess. They'll probably fix all of that for 5.1.1 which comes out this April.

Meanwhile just go: "draggable: false" and for now don't let your messagebox move.

Maybe you should report on that bug in Sencha's Extjs 5 "bugs" forum

Comment: Thanks for your help. but we solved it by removing the rtl from the viewport, and we added it to each frame and component separately.